# can you skip a single upgrade without cancelling the whole process?

Tags: linux, yum

When using yum and executing `yum upgrade`, the shell will automatically upgrade all packages that are eligible for upgrade.  If I come across a particular package that I do not need or want upgraded, is it possible to tell yum to skip that package and continue to the next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [manpage of Yum](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) has this option listed -

> **-x, --exclude=package**
>
> Exclude a specific package by name or glob from updates on all
>   repositories.  Configuration Option: exclude

Use it with `update` or `upgrade`. That should work.

Comment: I'm more referring to after the upgrade is in progress.  for example, if I need discover that the command is upgrading openoffice, but I decide I want to skip it without cancelling all of the upgrades. and starting over.

Comment: I think that's not possible. You can update selective package with wildcard(`*`) or skip the packages you want before starting the process with the `-x` option.